# How to prevent Intellij from creating a temporary run configuration and automatically switching to it

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij will create a greyed-out run configuration every time I execute an unsaved run operation from some menu, be that run a unit test, run a maven build, or some other execution from a menu item (there are a lot of ways to get a temporary run configuration).

These unsaved configurations are automatically switched to. Running anything changes the run configuration dropdown box at the top of the IDE, but I never asked for this behavior.

1. Is there a way to disable the automatic switching? I want to maintain my selection of the run configuration always and forever, amen. Stop Intellij from switching it for me.
2. Is there a way to disable the automatic creation of temporary run configurations, altogether? I never want to be bothered with temporary items in the run configuration inventory that I later feel like I need to clean up. Removes the clutter by never creating them in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, you can find it in Settings | Advanced Settings | IDE

[image]

Comment: can you embed the image in the answer. please?

Comment: In Rider 2022.2.2 it's under: Advanced Settings > Run/Debug section

Answer (score 5):

2021.1 version no longer has this setting, [issue reported](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-268436).

As a workaround you can close the project and edit `.idea/workspace.xml` file manually.

Under `<component name="PropertiesComponent">` node add/edit the following:

```
<property name="recentsLimit" value="0" />
```

---

For 2020.3.x and earlier versions:

Run/Debug Configurations | Templates | Temporary configurations limit: 0.

[image: Temporary configurations limit]

Comment: CrazyCoder, can you answer this question again for the latest version of intellij? they moved that control

Comment: they moved the control in version IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1 (Ultimate Edition) Build #IU-211.6693.111, -- i can't seem to find it in the same place, and i have searched for "Temporary" in the settings and ctrl+shift+a dialogs. it's no where to be found

Comment: @activedecay please follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-268436 for updates.

Comment: @activedecay please see the updated answer.