# Stop Rider from auto-selecting Run/Debug configuration

Tags: intellij-idea, rider

Is there a way from preventing Rider switching the Run/Debug configuration on its own? I'm talking about this dropdown:

[image]

I want to keep it on "WebAPI: Kestrel" unless I explicitly change it myself.

What happens instead is, if I go to my solution files, and right-click on one of the shell scripts I have, and click "run", it runs the script (which is fine), but it changes the default configuration to that script.. which is not what I want. Because then when I try to run my actual project, it runs the script again instead.

Any way of fixing this behavior and keeping the Run/Debug stuck on a configuration of my choosing?

Edit: If I do what CrazyCoder suggested, after setting the Temporary configurations limit to 0, I get a shorter list:

[image]

And then when I run a shell script again, it just goes to this:

[image]

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/64992890/104891 help?

Comment: @CrazyCoder - Thank you. It changes things a bit, I updated my answer with more details / screenshots.

Comment: It looks like a known bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-197080. It should help if you select your configuration again and run it.

Comment: Sigh.. ok, thanks a lot, I didn't stumble upon that before. Hopefully it gets fixed.

Comment: can't believe this still exists, it's so annoying. Also it appears like the linked bug is a different thing though....